# Undefined reference to POSIX functions when they're imported

Tags: c, time, timer, posix, real-time

I'm just creating a thread with a timer. Even if I import all the libraries I need. It keeps telling that there's no reference to the functions.

Exactly it says that `timer_create(...)` and `timer_settime(...)` are unreferenced.

These are my imports:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
```

And this is the thread where I use those functions:

```
void *Turismo(){
    const struct timespec periodo = {per_turismos_sec,per_turismos_nsec};
    struct sigevent event;
    timer_t timer;
    struct itimerspec its;
    sigset_t sigset;
    int signum;

    event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    event.sigev_signo = SIGRTMAX;
    event.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer;

    if(timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&event,&timer)!=0) error();

    its.it_interval = periodo;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 1;

    if(timer_settime(timer,0,&its,NULL)<0) error();
    if(sigemptyset(&sigset)<0) error();
    if(sigaddset(&sigset,SIGRTMAX)<0) error();


    while(1){
        sigwait(&sigset,&signum);
        // ESPECIFICACION DE LA TAREA

    }

    if(timer_delete(timer)<0) error();
    return NULL;
}
```

The code is not complete to make easir the correction.

For the compilation I'm using the next command:

```
gcc -o ejer1 ejer1.c -lpthread
```

I would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you linked the right library? Could you please post build command for the snippet?

Comment: If this is on Linux, notice that the manpages for these functions say "link with -lrt".

Comment: "undefined reference" (mentioned in the title) is not the same thing as "unreferenced" mentioned in the text.  Which is it?  "undefined reference" is a linker error not a compiler error - failure to include the appropriate header will result in an "_undeclared_ reference".  Inclusion "imports" declarations, not definitions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Think that maybe I'm not an english speaker and my Linux doesn't show me the error in English. I know perfectly how to copy and paste, but this is just a translate problem. Relax.

Comment: @wasanga7: One’s native language is irrelevant. Copying and pasting is a fundamental skill, independent of language. When reporting an error message, one reports it **exactly**, not by rewording or omitting. You do not have to know what “undefined reference” means in order to be able to copy those exact letters from where the computer prints them and to paste them into the question. We get an excessive number of questions where people fail to just copy the text, without change, into the question, and that causes a lot of wasted time. It is not a trivial issue; respect other people’s time.

Comment: Nonetheless, copy and paste the exact text and a translation. At the very least, do not say it is “Exactly” when it is not exact.

Comment: @wasanga7 for English error messages try `LC_ALL=C LANG=C gcc blablabla`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two stages to build the program

- Compilation
- Linkage

At the `compilation` stage, you need to know *declaration* of the functions and structures to build `.o` files.

At the `linkage` stage, you need actual implementation of the functions.

*Undefined reference* error tells you that the linker can not find the implementation of the functions.

Because you use third party library, you need to link that library with `-l` key.

To check if library has symbol, you can execute

```
$ nm -gD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so | grep timer_create
0000000000004520 T timer_create
00000000000042a0 T timer_create
```

In your case, you need to link `rt` library with `-lrt` key.

Comment: Thank you very much. It resolved my problem just adding `-lrt` to the command.

Comment: Glad to help, wish you high achievements with programming.